# Does my adapter work?

Tags: java, android

I get inputs from the user and then put them in a `ListView`, but when I click on the button, it works with no errors, opening the layout and immediately closing it. When I try with `arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, m_list);`, it works perfect.

```
public class HomeChat extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    EditText writeSms;

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    ArrayList<String>  m_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String emriUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_chat);

        writeSms = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.shkrunSms);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


        emriUser = getIntent().getExtras().getString("emri");

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_chat,m_list);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    }


    public void sentSmsButton(View view) {

      String  mesazhet = emriUser + ": " + writeSms.getText().toString();

        if (writeSms != null && writeSms.length() > 0) {

            m_list.add(mesazhet);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            writeSms.setText("");

        }else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the chat layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test123"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `ArrayAdapter` is expecting a layout with only a single `TextView` in it. So, your layout with a `LinearLayout` containing a `TextView` won't work. Try changing `R.layout.list_chat` to simply:

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/test123"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:background="#cccccc"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    />
```